# What would make people choose open-pit quarrying instead of tunnel mining?

Tags: mining

I want to describe a mining town, but I envision the tunnel-type of mine, not an open quarry. All the stones/minerals that fits with the world, however, seem to have been typically extracted from open quarries. Is it feasible for a people to choose to extract these minerals (tuff, for example) from tunnels rather than cutting into an open pit? Or would deciding upon a different resource be more realistic?

Comment: This question seems more suited to our sister site: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know about tuff, but in pre-modern times limestone was extracted from underground mines. And chalk too. In fact, as far as I know, open-quarry mining was limited to various kind of construction stone. I know of no open-quarry mine of iron ore or coal in pre-modern times. What exact resources are you speaking about? It's kind of important.

Comment: @Anewnormal. Even an underground mine will have considerable signs of it's presence on the surface.  You have to have spoil tips ("slag heaps") and there is water to pump out.   Then you need the infrastructure to move materials in and out, not to mention places for people to do people things.

Comment: Tuff is a bulky material used for construction, cheap and easy is paramount for materials like that. you really want them mining something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change what they are mining. Tuff is basically cut into blocks which is much easier in a an open pit mine. It is also used for construction so it has to be both cheap and abundant so open mines are the only way it will happen.

You can get what you want easily by changing what is being mined. I suggest **silver,  salt, copper, or tin**. There are plenty of tunnel mines in the medieval era and older. Seam mining often involved tunnels just because removing the huge amounts of rock to follow a seam was impractical. the bulkier and closer to the surface the material you are mining the better pit mining works. Conversely the less bulky and the deeper it is the better tunnels work. In the modern world open pit mining is a lot easier due to have excavation machinery, so the modern mining methods are not a good measure.

[image]

The simple geology of the deposit has a strong effect, drift and slope mines can be  profitable for a long time, while shaft mines tend to flood so are often small.

valuable metals often favored tunnels, as you are removing a small amount of material. Roman gold and silver mines were often tunnel mines.

Dry areas often favor tunnel mining, flooding was a problem with mining down but dry or high elevations could make larger tunnel mines possible.

Mountainous horizontal seams had little flooding risk, so flooding risk is minimized so huge complex tunnel mines could be excavated.

Salt often favored tunnel mines, generally you want your salt mine as dry as possible, a pit mine may turn it into a lake. There are some HUGE underground medieval salt mines.

here is an a plan for a real medieval silver mine 
[image]

Comment: +1, just want to add that John did not pock his list (salt, gold, silver, copper, tin) randomly so use one of those unless there is a specific reason otherwise. Salt would be closest to your example?

Comment: Another factor in modern open pit mining is that you are often using chemical techniques like heap leaching to extract tiny amounts of material from large amounts of rock.  E.g. gold mines in Nevada's Carlin Trend are extracting 0.20 to 0.25 ounces of gold per ton of rock: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlin%E2%80%93type_gold_deposit  Compare that to Gold Rush era mines that had visible amounts of gold in e.g. quartz veins.

Answer (score 2):

### Exposed Sedimentary Layers in a Canyon Wall

The thing that makes pit mining make sense is situations where a valuable resource exists in a sheet near the surface.  However, these same sheets can become quite deep when you are talking about sedimentary layers.  If you are looking at a layer of tuff that was formed 300 million years ago instead of 3 million years ago, it could be quite deep, but also accessible from the wall of a canyon.  In this case, it would make a lot more since to tunnel in from the side to extract it than to dig away the whole top of the canyon ridge to get to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open-pit is generally (there are exceptions) easier, safer, and cheaper for large volumes located near the surface.

- Open-pit tends to be harder to drain, to secure from trespassing and wildlife, and to be less dramatic in a story. But modern technology can mitigate the first two quite readily.

[image: Coal mine in Wyoming]

So it depends upon what you're mining, how deep it is, and the technology available.